# Array List wont recognize photos when using file path

Tags: java, arrays, image, javafx, imageview

My program creates a Black Jack game using a JavaFX GUI, however when I am inputting photos into the deck (ArrayList) it is not populating the ArrayList with the image paths. The paths are all very similar, they are c1.png or c2.png etc.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            deck.add(new Image("file:images/c" + (i+1) + ".png"));
        }
```

It should display images into JavaFX GUI when hard coded it works, but won't work in for loop

Comment: Question. Are you sure this `new Image("file:images/c" + (i+1) + ".png")`  is the right way? Try `new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\images\\" + (i+1) + ".png"));` Check this out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_images.htm. Also, is the `ArrayList<Image>`?

Comment: Are your images **resources**? If so, get rid of the `file:` scheme and use the absolute path to your images relative to the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  deck.add(new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\images\\" + (i+1) + ".png"));
}
```

Also, make sure to cast your `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Image>`:

```
List<Image> deck = new ArrayList<Image>();
```

Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: If you don't use a static path, then you need to get the resource which I think it is something like `getClass().getResource("path/to/file/andFilename.extension");`

Comment: Shouldn't you close the `FileInputStream`? after you're done with it?

Comment: @MikaelF, I leave that level of details to the author of the question. Personally, I would use a Try-With-Resources since `FileInputStream` implements the `Closeable` and `AutoCloseable` interface. I.e.: `try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.txt")) { ... }`. This will call the `close()` method of `FileInputStream` for you.